# Routing with multiple NICs on debian

Tags: networking, debian, linux-networking

I have a machine with two NICs on different network segments, I've set up routing for the different segments.

It works if I run all the routing commands manually, but I can't get it to work when putting the commands in the `/etc/network/interfaces`-file, what am I doing wrong?

When I run the commands "by hand" it answers on both interfaces, when I put them in /etc/network/interfaces, it doesn't.
I suspect I am doing something in the wrong order or something like that. What am I missing?

The commands I'm running(this works):

```
 ip route add 192.168.85.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.85.94 table internal
 ip route add default via 192.168.85.1 table internal
 ip route add 212.16.165.128/28 dev eth1 src 212.16.165.131 table external
 ip route add default via 212.16.165.129 table external
 ip route add 192.168.85.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.85.94
 ip route add 212.16.165.128/28 dev eth1 src 212.16.165.131
 ip route add default via 192.168.85.1
 ip rule add from 192.168.85.94 table internal
 ip rule add from 212.16.165.131 table external
```

Here's the `/etc/network/interfaces`-file in it's current non-working setup:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.85.94
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.85.1
up ip route add 192.168.85.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.85.94 table internal
up ip route add default via 192.168.85.1 table internal
up ip route add 192.168.85.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.85.94
up ip route add default via 192.168.85.1
up ip rule add from 192.168.85.94 table internal

# External network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.0.131
netmask 255.255.255.240
up ip route add 192.168.0.128/28 dev eth1 src 192.168.0.131 table external
up ip route add default via 192.168.0.129 table external
up ip route add 192.168.0.128/28 dev eth1 src 192.168.0.131
up ip rule add from 192.168.0.131 table external
```

Most of the information on the setup is from here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

Comment: try to comment "gateway 192.168.85.1" and "up ip route add default via 192.168.85.1" you need to default gw via ip routes tables

Comment: But why does it work when I run the commands "by hand" and not when I put them in /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: Checkout my [related answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316362/112550): try to remove all manual configuration before using *ifupdown*.